# Difference in view hierarchy when adding a child VC in code or IB

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uicontainerview

Iv'e noticed something quite weird, when I add a child VC to a view hierarchy in IB the hierarchy looks like this

parent vc view
 - -container view
 - - - -child vc view

when adding it by hand

parent vc view
 - - child vc view

Following the instructions from apple, in their [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html), they never talk about the container view as part of the hierarchy, however in the code in practice, for example when I am trying to call

```
    - (void) hideContentController: (UIViewController*) content {
   [content willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
   [content.view removeFromSuperview];
   [content removeFromParentViewController];
}
```

the container view is still "polluting" my view hierarchy. I don't understand the relationship between that container and my child `VC`.

A practical example in my code, is that I put these `viewControllers` in a `UIStackView` and when trying to remove the `UIViewController` that was inserted with an `Embed Segue`, I remain with a phantom view. The only way I could find to get access to that view, is an `IBOutlet` from storyboard.

Anyone have experience in handling, replacing or removing `ChildViewControllers` added with IB? Or can explain where the difference is coming from and how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the "container view" you can use in IB is a bit, well... misleading?

If you select it in the Object Library pane, you get an info popup that lists it as `UIContainerView`. However, if you search Apple's documentation, that is nowhere to be found.

And, as you have probably noticed, if you connect it with an `IBOutlet`, it gets set as a `UIView`.... and if you try to do something like:

```
UIContainerView *vc;
```

or

```
let cv: UIContainerView?
```

you'll get a "Use of undeclared type" error.

What makes it "different" is only how it behaves in IB, and the automatic "load-and-display" of its embedded Child View Controller. This is much like Segues... you can create and "see" them in IB; you can assign properties to them; at run-time they server a purpose / have actions; but... you cannot create a `UISegue` in code.

So... if you want to use the visual design-and-embed automation of "container views" in IB, you need to be aware that it is added as a `UIView` to your view hierarchy, and the `.view` of its `embedded` VC is added as a ***subview to itself***... and you'll need to use `IBOutlet` to have a reference to it at runtime if you want to remove it (or size it or change any other property of it).

When you see "code only" implementations of Child View Controllers, you generally ***also*** see code for adding the Child VC's view as a subview of the "main" view (or some other view).  It just doesn't seem related to the `UIContainerView` you can use in IB, because it's never referenced that way.

Does that make sense?